# How to create dynamic path attribute value in Spring JSP JSTL

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, annotations, jstl

For better understanding of my question look at below JSP code.

```
<c:forEach var="technologyLocation" items="${model.technologyLocationList}" varStatus="loop">
    <form:input path="technologyLocationList[${loop.index}].location"/>         
</c:forEach>
```

Relation between Technology and TechnologyLocation is OneToMany in my spring pojo code.
Above code will render number of input elements equal to number of location data available in database with correct path attribute value for input element.

My problem is:

I am not getting how to render form input element in case no TecnologyLocation records are available in db. Because, in that case, empty input element will need to be render with correct path attribute value. So that user can enter new location for persisting in db.

If record exists in db then also show one empty input elements apart from available location input element, so that user can update existing and save new one as well.

Please suggest how I can achieve this with valid path attribute value!

I am using spring and hibernate for persisting data using annotations.

Thanks in advance!

Please look at below for relevant part of code!

Technology.java

```
public class Technology{
.
.
  private List<TechnologyLocation> technologyLocationList = new ArrayList<TechnologyLocation>(0);
.
.
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "technology")
public List<TechnologyLocation> getTechnologyLocationList() {
    return technologyLocationList;
}

public void setTechnologyLocationList(List<TechnologyLocation> technologyLocationList) {
    this.technologyLocationList = technologyLocationList;
}
}
```

TechnologyLocation.java

```
public class TechnologyLocation{
.
@NotNull
private Technology technology;

public TechnologyLocation(Technology technology) {
    this.technology = technology;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="technology_id")
public Technology getTechnology()
{
    return technology;
}

public void setTechnology( Technology technology )
{
    this.technology = technology;
}

@Column(name="technology_location")
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
}
```

TechnologyController.java

```
public class TechnologyController{
// Problem in getting better way to get new technology location from JSP. I don't want like request.getPrameter(paramname). I want to use power of hibernate with spring, something like form  input element with path attribute for accepting new entry for location from jsp
}
```

Technology.jsp

```
<div>
     <span>Location</span>
     <c:forEach var="technologyLocation" items="${model.technologyLocationList}" varStatus="loop">
          <form:input path="technologyLocationList[${loop.index}].location"/>
   </c:forEach>
   <!--Confusion: If list size is zero, I need to show empty form input element for entering new location-->
   <form:input path="some thing should be like technologyLocationList?.location so that we can use power of hibernate"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean but i'll give it a try.

One approach would be to prepend your technologyLocationList in the Controller with a null-Element for TechnologyLocation of your choice. 
After that, the `${model.technologyLocationList}` will never be empty and additionally you can use `<c:if>` to provide appropriate handling for the null-Element in the JSP, e.g. another input field for adding a custom location.

If you post your controller and pojo code I can improve my answer.

**EDIT : IMPROVEMENT 1** (As your Controller is missing, I have to guess some parts of your code)

Try to add the following in your Controller method for publishing the model:

```
Technology technology = // your method to load it from Database
TechnologyLocation nullLocation = new TechnologyLocation(technology);
List<TechnologyLocation> technologyLocations = technology.getTechnologyLocationList();
if (technologyLocationList.isEmpty()) {
    technologyLocationList.add(nullLocation);
}
model.addAttribute("technology", technology);
```

In your JSP:

```
<form:form commandName="technology">
    <c:foreach items="${technology.technologyLocationList}" var="technologyLocation">
        <form:input path="technologyLocation.location"/>
    </c:foreach> 
</form:form>
```

That way, if your Database for TechnologyLocations is empty, the Technology object on the web page contains a new non-persistent Location, which can be edited in case of its location String and which should be persisted, when you submit your Form.

Comment: Hi Jeyp, thanks for trying to provide help! As you was asking, I am posting my source code in my post!

Comment: I added an improvement to my answer.

Comment: That may be better than what I did for solving! Can you please tell what changes in JSP I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I got it way of solving my own problem. I added one new property newTechnologyLocation of string type in pojo, make it transient for avoiding db related exception like column not existing etc. I used property newTechnologyLocation as a value of path attribute for new entry like below.

```
<form:input path="newTechnologyLocation"/>
```

and in controller get value and persist it in db as a new record as like below:

```
technologyInstance.getNewTechnologyLocation()
```